# onclick on element that is inside other that is used by onclick too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is such question here, but I tried solution and in my case this doesn't work.
I have a form that opens by click on it and then it must be closed by clicking x that is inside this form.
[This variant](http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/7/) doesn't fit, because cookie doesn't sets to on after closing form.
If I open set it on [close click](http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/8/) This doesn't works too because click on x calls click event of all form.
If I do like in [solution, I find in stackoverflow](http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/9/) the form doesn't opens at all.
Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('techSupport') == null) {
        $.cookie('techSupport', 'off');
    } else if ($.cookie('techSupport') == 'on') {
        $.cookie('techSupport', 'off');
    };
}).on("click", "div#techSupport", function (event) {
    if ($.cookie("techSupport") == 'off') {
        $.cookie("techSupport", "on");
        var res = "<nobr><div>Technical support<a href='#' id='closeChat'>x</a></div></nobr>\n" +
            "<div id='chatBox'>What's your probloem?</div>\n" +
            "<textarea id='messageBox'></textarea>\n" +
            "<button id='sendToSupport'>Send</button>";
        $(this).css("width", "200px");
        $(this).css("height", "400px");
        $(this).html(res);
    }
}).on("click", "div#techSupport,a#closeChat", function () {
    var res = "<div id='techSupport'>techsupport</div>";
    $("div#techSupport").html(res);
    $("div#techSupport").css("width", "100px");
    $("div#techSupport").css("height", "10px");
    console.log($("div#techSupport").html());
    $.cookie("techSupport","off");
    event.stopPropagation();
    //window.location.reload();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="techSupport">techsupport</div>
```

So how can I click on cross ignoring the main form?

Comment: Is this line correct?: `}).on("click", "div#techSupport,a#closeChat", function () {` This looks to me like it is binding the event to both `div#techSupport`, and `a#closeChat`, is that what you want to be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here, stop the propagation of the event in `onclick` of `a#closeChat` (note I also added the `e` parameter at your handler):

```
.on("click", "a#closeChat", function (e) {
    var res = "<div id='techSupport'>techsupport</div>";
    $("div#techSupport").html(res);
    $("div#techSupport").css("width", "100px");
    $("div#techSupport").css("height", "10px");
    console.log($("div#techSupport").html());
    $.cookie("techSupport","off");
    e.stopPropagation();
    //window.location.reload();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/10/

OR

Inspect the `target` property of the `event` on the `div#techSupport` handler:

```
if ($.cookie("techSupport") == 'off' && event.target.id != 'closeChat') {
    $.cookie("techSupport", "on");
    var res = "<nobr><div>Technical support<a href='#' id='closeChat'>x</a></div></nobr>\n" +
        "<div id='chatBox'>What's your probloem?</div>\n" +
        "<textarea id='messageBox'></textarea>\n" +
        "<button id='sendToSupport'>Send</button>";
    $(this).css("width", "200px");
    $(this).css("height", "400px");
    $(this).html(res);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/11/

The best solution will depend on each use case.